# Firefox word-break for inline elements

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, word-break

I'm trying to change the `word-break` property for certain inline elements such as `<span>` and `<a>` to get a better flow of the page's content.

It seems, that Firefox only recognises the word-break property for elements that are displayed as block (such as `<div>`), whereas Chrome honours the request to break the words.

In the example below, the red and blue parts render identically in Chrome (the xxxxx is broken over several lines). In Firefox, the xxxxx in the red box overflows.

```html
<div style="width:200px;background:red;">
  Hello <span style="word-break:break-all;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span> World
</div>

<div style="width:200px;background:blue;word-break:break-all;">
  Hello <span>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span> World
</div>
```

Example from above: https://jsfiddle.net/7scx4hfq/

Which browser is behaving correctly? Is it a Firefox bug or a Chrome bug?

And more importantly, how can I achieve the desired effect in all browsers?

**Note**, setting `word-break:break-all` at a block level is not an option.

Comment: I'm always confused as to the the use case for a 50 letter word. Can you come up with a **practical** example?

Comment: The use case are long links that are spelled out in text that is justified. Normal word breaks only break the URL at the slashes "/" which results in very large ugly gaps for the remaining word. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/zL8ytno6/
You get such ugly links for example with links to Flickr and Google Drive.

Comment: @Paulie_D Users enter text completely unpredictably.

Comment: @kaymes I have the more or less the same problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465092/word-break-break-all-css-property-doesn-t-seem-to-work-on-span). Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding the extra `word-wrap: break-word;` for Firefox.

```
span {
  word-break: break-all; /* for others */
  word-wrap: break-word;  /* for Firefox */
}
```

If you want to maintain all the text in the same line as much as possible, you can set `white-space: nowrap;` on the container, and reset it to `white-space: normal;` on the `span`. Again, those settings are just for Firefox.

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
  background: aqua;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello <span>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span> World
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yw06erhj/)**

Comment: This changes the behaviour of the span in such a way that the text doesn't flow normally any more. In this example it results in line breaks after "Hello" and before "World". See https://jsfiddle.net/7scx4hfq/1/

Comment: I updated it above. Note the word "Hello" is not inside the <span>, so that setting the wrapping on the div and the span the results will not be the same.

Comment: The break-word has the same effect extra line breaks because it still tries to keep as much of the word together as possible. This is particularly an issue if the text is justified.
 https://jsfiddle.net/7scx4hfq/3/

Comment: Which one of the blocks is the output you want to have (either in Chrome or Firefox), can you attach an image?

Comment: The version I'm after is the red one on Chrome: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eumky3zhdtlesa9/Selection_010.png?dl=0

Comment: I updated again above, now it outputs the same results for both Firefox and Chrome.