# `word-break: break-all` CSS property doesn’t seem to work on span

Tags: html, css, word-break

The following snippet consists of two examples. The first sets the `word-break: break-all` property on the div, the second sets it on the span.

```css
.break-all {
  word-break: break-all;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='break-all'>
  <span>qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwerty</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <span class='break-all'>qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwerty</span>
</div>
```

In Firefox, in the first example, the word is broken to fit into the div around it, but in the second example it’s not broken at all. What’s the reason for this?

In Chromium, the word is broken the same way in both examples.

It seems like it works on block elements, but not on inline elements (it was pointed out in the comments that adding `display: block` to the span results in the word being broken).

Comment: `display:block;` could have something to do with that. If you add it, it works.

Comment: change the property of display property of span to block or inline-block to get it work.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149536/firefox-word-break-for-inline-elements?rq=1) also suggests using ```word-wrap: break-word``` to correct this in FF, in case you need the elements to behave as inline (though ```inline-block``` should work too).  Still not sure why this occurs though.

Comment: Whoops, human error! Updated with the right URL.

Comment: The question could probably rephrased to "why does it work on block elements, but not on inline elements?"